# Каким образом facebook определяет по slug это страница или пользователь?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, nginx

Например: fb.com/maybeUserOrPage при входе на данную ссылку, может отобразиться как facebook страница, так же facebook пользователь, зависит пользователю или странице принадлежит данный slug. Каким образом facebook определяет откуда брать данные, с users - таблички или с pages таблички, как можно организовать подобное правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Простая MySQL таблица вида

```
| slug   | type | id  |
=======================
| Ivan   |  0   | 123 |
| Russia |  1   | 54  |
```

Где `type` вида ENUM(0,1). Для человека значение 0, для компании/страницы 1.
id будет ссылаться на ключ в соотвествующей таблице, скажем `users` и `pages`.